# How to add exclude data in Firebase rules on multiple levels?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have my rules set. Normally, all data can only be read by the person who is auth to do so. However, I want to make exceptions. These are my rules:

```
 "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        "ForEveryone": {
        ".read": true,
          ".write": true
        }
        "NoWrite" : {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": false
        }
      }
    }
```

So I let's say I have 3 string. String 1 is called private and can the auth person can read and write. String 2 is `ForEveryone`, so everyone can change and write data. String 3 is `NoWrite`, for everyone but you can not write to it.

I get an error, saying:`Expecting a ; or " at the line NoWrite`. So what am I doing wrong? Is it a wrong placed `}`? Thank you.

Comment: First, you are missing a comma just above the "NoWrite", right after the closing paren. Are your ForEveryone and NoWrite nodes actually children of the users/uid parent node?

Answer (score 2):

The approach you're taking to your rule structure won't work. Firebase security rules cascade, meaning that a permission given to any node will apply to any of its children and on down the tree. You cannot grant read or write access on a node and then revoke it further down. (But you *can* grant permissions not granted above.) See the [docs on rule cascading](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade).

In your case, you want to have some user data that be can written to by anyone and some that cannot. It's not clear from your example whether you want `NoWrite` to be written only by the authenticated user, or by nobody. Depending on [how you will be reading this data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-structuring-db), you will need to either separate these data into different collections, or make `$uid` inaccessible and define your rules only for `ForEveryone` and `NoWrite`.

The first approach might look like this:

```
 "rules": {
    "users-public": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "true",
      },
    "users-nowrite": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
```

Or the second, like this:

```
 "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        "ForEveryone": {
          ".read": "true",
          ".write": "true"
        },
        "NoWrite" : {
          ".read": "true",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
```

As to your syntax error, you need a comma `,` after the closing brace before `"NoWrite"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your rules, properly spaced so you can see the relationship between the parent nodes and child nodes. It seems this is not what you want. So this isn't really an answer but will lead to a better question that we can answer. Will update once we know what the OP is after.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
           "$uid": {
               ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
               ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
               "ForEveryone": {
                   ".read": true,
                   ".write": true
               },
               "NoWrite" : {
                   ".read": true,
                   ".write": false
               }
           } //end uid
         } //end users
     } //end rules
} //outside closure
```

Comment: I don't know if it was intentional but you did fix OP's problem.